# What word could be used for a thing that holds a measure that lies between true and false?

Tags: single-word-requests

In fuzzy logic a value can be partially true so I could present it as a degree of truth.

However, I'm looking for a word for this thing that contains a measure that lies between true and false.

The quality of the measure might be called fuzziness or it might be called a fuzzy value.

However, in conventional logic there's a boolean that can be either true or false.

So is there a word for the fuzzy equivalent? Or can you think of way of expressing this otherwise?

Comment: In your second sentence, you ask for something with false-trueness but in your question you ask for things lying in between truth and fallacy. They're different : Something appearing to be true and something that can be both a truth or fallacy.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Do you have an example in mind of something that can be both truth and false?

Comment: schrodinger's cat, or a tossed coin (that can take two values)

Comment: But this is only because you are waiting or wanting a certain value. Suppose you want the head of a coin it. You toss it in the air. it can take any value as long as it is in the air.

Comment: ***verisimilitude***.

Comment: ambiguous maybe

Comment: **Truthiness?**

Comment: Subjectivity comes to mind. The truth is in the eyes of the beholder.

Comment: @Max Williams Truthiness would be in the right direction. It would just have a touch of bias as 50% truthiness would also be 50% falsiness.

Comment: @DanBron Nice word. Didn't know that one :) .

In this case fuzziness is more along the lines of saying how true (or false) something is.

The concept is also used for, say, having minute intermediate states between hot and cold.

Comment: @hypeJunction Subjectivity is a good angle. Neither saying it's true or false. One could definitely say that something is subjectively true for one or more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a search around and it looks like the equivalent of a *boolean* variable is a *fuzzy* variable.

As *boolean* got its name from George Boole and the term fuzzy logic was introduced by a certain Lotfi Zadeh perhaps the neologism *zadehean* could be added.

Edit: Two examples of existing usage have been found.

> You'll love the new term for fuzzy logic that is starting to appear:
>   "Zadehean logic", after Lofti Zadeh, one of the original fuzzy
>   theorists.

[Source](http://www.piclist.com/techref/postbot.asp?by=thread&id=Logic&w=body&tgt=post)

> For example DNF and CNF expressions for [...] are stated as below for
>   Zadehean and Boolean set theories

[Source](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/12296/1/NQ35169.pdf)